# How to prevent memoryOutOfBound exception while performing HBase Scan?

Tags: hbase

I am too much confused between Caching , BlockSize and MaxResultSIze. I have gone through almost all StackOverFlow Questions.

I am writing a HBase client using Java and I want to prevent my client to go out of memory issue.

What should be the optimal values of Caching, Blocksize & MaxResultSize.

Will be helpful if anyone can explain with examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you client perspective caching and block size does not matter, max result size is relevant.

Caching means if hbase should cache the values scan returned to client, so if you scan same values again data will return from memory cache, not disk. If you use same data for a lot of query you can enable cache in Scan object. For example when working on last hour data with 100s jobs, you should cache last hour data in memory if you have enough memory. Basically caching is performance related, does not cause out of memory, and hbase manages cache memory itself in server side.

Block size is also a hbase server side performance related parameter and does not effect client memory consumption.

Max result size is what you should be careful about. If you store every scan `Result` object or some part of this object in your client application memory, you should consider a reasonable result count according to your available memory. BUT if you want you can pass a full scan to 10s of gb table and process every `Result` in for loop with scan result iterator, to count rows or column keys in a table with only 512mb memory or less. This does not require you store data in your client and in for loop a `Result` is temporary variable which will be garbage collected shortly.

So it depends what you want to do with `Results` of `Scan`, if you want to store them in memory for some kind of in-memory calculation, you should have enough memory or change your processing logic.

I hope, i could helped.

Comment: Thank you halil.. Its nice explanation.